# rsync --exclude and --exclude-from doesn't work

Tags: filesystems, rsync, exclude

I've had a command in a script which I used a lot for a couple years. I didn't use the script for the last year, but today I ran it again. I'm suddenly having trouble excluding files from an rsync though.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 (rsync version 3.1.2) and I run the following command:

```
rsync -exclude-from='sync_exclude.txt' -azvv -e ssh '.' root@146.xx.xx.xx:~/wp
```

where the `sync_exclude.txt` file looks like this:

```
$ cat sync_exclude.txt
.idea
.git
.gitignore
.DS_Store
sync_exclude.txt
ansible/*
.env
```

But to my surprise the rsync now also syncs all the things in this exclude file.

I've tried other variations, such as

```
rsync -exclude=.git/ -azvv -e ssh '.' root@146.xx.xx.xx:~/wp
rsync -exclude=".git/" -azvv -e ssh '.' root@146.xx.xx.xx:~/wp
rsync -exclude=/.git/ -azvv -e ssh '.' root@146.xx.xx.xx:~/wp
rsync -exclude=/.git/* -azvv -e ssh '.' root@146.xx.xx.xx:~/wp
rsync -exclude /.git/ -azvv -e ssh '.' root@146.xx.xx.xx:~/wp
rsync -exclude /.git/* -azvv -e ssh '.' root@146.xx.xx.xx:~/wp
rsync -exclude="/.git/*" -azvv -e ssh '.' root@146.xx.xx.xx:~/wp
rsync -exclude "/.git/*" -azvv -e ssh '.' root@146.xx.xx.xx:~/wp
rsync -exclude={.git/,"ansible/*"} -azvv -e ssh '.' root@146.xx.xx.xx:~/wp
rsync -exclude {.git/,"ansible/*"} -azvv -e ssh '.' root@146.xx.xx.xx:~/wp
etc.
```

But none of them exclude the `.git/` or the `ansible/` folder. I've also tried on MacOS, but I have the same problem there.

I'm banging my head against the wall why none of this would suddenly work anymore.

Could anybody help me out of my misery?

Answer (score 2):

This might just be a typo, but you have to use `--exclude-from` instead of `-exclude-from` (notice the double hyphen there).

Comment: Same for `--exclude`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't add comment. I think you should add relative path to the file sync_exclude.txt. Example:

```
rsync --exclude-from='/path-relative/sync_exclude.txt' -azvv -e ssh '.' root@146.xx.xx.xx:~/wp
```

If that doesn't work try this (add `--relative` option):

```
rsync --relative --exclude-from='/path-relative/sync_exclude.txt' -azvv -e ssh '.' root@146.xx.xx.xx:~/wp
```

and also try changing this to relative path:

```
$ cat sync_exclude.txt

/path-relative/.idea
/path-relative/.git
/path-relative/.gitignore
/path-relative/.DS_Store
/path-relative/sync_exclude.txt
/path-relative/ansible/*
/path-relative/.env
```